# Flash Printing only prints what is visible on a canvas

Tags: flash, apache-flex, actionscript-3, printing, air

I am building a very basic report writer for an AIR application that I am developing.  I am using the Flash PrintJob class to output the contents of my report (in which pages are stored as Canvas objects in a ViewStack object).  The problem is, only the content that I see in the report preview screen gets printed.   Is there a way that I can print what the Canvas object contains not just what is visible?

Thanks very much for your help.

Here is a code snippet that I am using:

```
        protected function doPrintReport(event:Event):void
        {
            var pj:PrintJob = new PrintJob();
            var pjo:PrintJobOptions = new PrintJobOptions();

            CursorManager.setBusyCursor();

            if(pj.start() == true) {

                if(vsOutput.orientation == "landscape") {
                    pj.orientation = PrintJobOrientation.LANDSCAPE;
                                    }
                else {
                    pj.orientation = PrintJobOrientation.PORTRAIT;
                }
                for(var i:int = 0; i < vsOutput.length; i++) {
                    var pc:Canvas = new Canvas();
                    pc = vsOutput.getChildAt(i) as Canvas;
                    pj.addPage(pc, null, pjo);
                }
            }
            else {
                CursorManager.removeBusyCursor();
                MsgBox.error("Failed to initiate printing", "Printing Error");
                return;
            }

            try{
                pj.send();
            }
            catch(e:Error)
            {
                CursorManager.removeBusyCursor();
                MsgBox.error(e.toString(), "Printing Error");
                return;
            }

            CursorManager.removeBusyCursor();
            MsgBox.info("Print request sent successfully", "Print Request");
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to add all canvas objects to PrintJob. Use [addObject](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/printing/FlexPrintJob.html#addObject%28%29) for that

It would be nice to see your code if it doesn't work

Comment: thanks, there is only an addPage method for the Flash PrintJob Class, the FlexPrintJob didn't seem to give me the flexibility I needed. I've added the method that I use to print the output...  Thanks again for taking a look.